# Equation of objects surrounding me

Tags: circles

In the equation of a circle the point $x$, $y$ lie on the circle because they satisfy the equation: $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

Question:
Similarly, is it possible to write equation for 3-dimensional objects that are lying in my surrounding?

These points should satisfy the equation so that these points form a 3-dimensional object.

Comment: I think the concept you are thinking of is called _Locus_. As in the example given below, we can consider a collection of all points that satisfy some criterion and write an equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics)

Comment: Is it possible to write equation for any 3-dimensional objects that are lying in my surrounding?

Comment: It is very possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a sphere:

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2 $$